# Error "The method createUser(String, int) is undefined for the type UserManager"

Tags: android, multi-user, usermanager

I am trying to create new User using `UserManager` service on android KK 4.4 ( Multi-user)

```
    mUserManager = (UserManager)getSystemService(Context.USER_SERVICE);
    mUserManager.createUser("USER NAME", 0);
```

I can access all other APIs in `UserManager` using `mUserManager` without giving any error but `createUser` is showing error "The method `createUser(String, int)` is undefined for the type `UserManager`".

I can see `createUser` is defined in `UserManager` class.

Can somebody please help me on this in case there's anything I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you refer to the [documentation for `UserManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/UserManager.html), you'll see that no `createUser` method is listed. Even though the method is defined in the Android source code, and exists in the framework installed on the device, it's not part of the public API, so it's not present in the Android SDK; that is, it isn't in the android.jar that you link your app against.

It may still be possible to access it using reflection, but I rather suspect that the service backing this call will disallow non-system apps from calling it, in which case you'll get a `SecurityException` at runtime.